# Can I still access the side quests from The Waking Sands after this event?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

Few main quests afterwards, I will be no longer able to access The Waking Sands because

> The Scions are falling back from The Waking Sands to move to a more neutral area of Revenant's Toll.

However, I didn't clear the quests originating from there to spare them for the extra jobs. This is problematic because to actually become a Machinist, I have to proceed through the main quest and get past the problematic part of the storyline. In an extreme case, I am worried about being locked out of hard and extreme primals just because of my EXP greed.

Well, can I proceed without fear? Can I still accept these quests, **especially** harder primals, even after that happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, these quests will still be there even after the event. You will be in a different, instanced area at first but once you get past that point all of the side quests will be moved into the far left room after you enter the waking sands.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only the Hard and Extreme Primal quest you don't have to worry about it. You'll be able to take the quest with no problem.

But if it's general quest I really am not so sure.